# perl regex in string to be ignored

Tags: regex, perl

I have the following string in `$word`. I'm translating this with google translate to `$translatedword` and then replace it in a file like in the following code:

```
my $word = "This is an example text (with) ";


my $translatedword =googletranslate ( $word);
open ( $in, "< " . $filename );
open ( $out, "> " . $tmpfile );
while( <$in> ) {
        $_ =~ s/$word/$translatedword/;
        print $out $_;
}
close $out;
close $in;
```

That goes well (the translated text is replaced by original text) as long as there are no ()/[]$ etc are in play. in this case the parentheses will cause the  text not to be replaced in the file.
i tried this:

```
my $newword = "\Q" . $word . "\E";
```

and this:

```
my $newword = quotemeta( $word );
```

but both are not giving a solution..

Any hints on what i might be doing wrong are appreciated.

Comment: Your example is confusing in a number of respects.  Since you don't provide any information on `googletranslate()`, I have to assume it's not relevant to the problem and that your problem boils down to: _How do I perform a substitution when the original string contains metacharacters?_ The read- and write-filehandles are also superfluous to the problem.  `s/\Q$string\E/$translated_string/;` should work.

Comment: If you print word at line 2 does it have the special characters? I think you're issue is quotes and double quotes. As explained here http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfunc.html#qq%2fSTRING%2f

Comment: James, indeed the translate part is not relevant. I tried what you suggested and that worked. problem solved, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Change the loop to

```
while( <$in> ) {
  $_ =~ s/\Q$word\E/$translatedword/;
  print $out $_;
}
```